# Manipulate pandas columns with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform

Please see this SO post [Manipulating pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431911/manipulating-pandas-columns)

I shared this dataframe:

```
+----------+------------+-------+-----+------+
| Location |    Date    | Event | Key | Time |
+----------+------------+-------+-----+------+
| i2       | 2019-03-02 |     1 | a   |      |
| i2       | 2019-03-02 |     1 | a   |      |
| i2       | 2019-03-02 |     1 | a   |      |
| i2       | 2019-03-04 |     1 | a   |    2 |
| i2       | 2019-03-15 |     2 | b   |    0 |
| i9       | 2019-02-22 |     2 | c   |    0 |
| i9       | 2019-03-10 |     3 | d   |      |
| i9       | 2019-03-10 |     3 | d   |    0 |
| s8       | 2019-04-22 |     1 | e   |      |
| s8       | 2019-04-25 |     1 | e   |      |
| s8       | 2019-04-28 |     1 | e   |    6 |
| t14      | 2019-05-13 |     3 | f   |      |
+----------+------------+-------+-----+------+
```

This is a follow-up question. Consider two more columns after Date as shown below.

```
+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Start Time (hh:mm:ss) | Stop Time (hh:mm:ss) |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
| 13:24:38              | 14:17:39             |
| 03:48:36              | 04:17:20             |
| 04:55:05              | 05:23:48             |
| 08:44:34              | 09:13:15             |
| 19:21:05              | 20:18:57             |
| 21:05:06              | 22:01:50             |
| 14:24:43              | 14:59:37             |
| 07:57:32              | 09:46:21 
| 19:21:05              | 20:18:57             |
| 21:05:06              | 22:01:50             |
| 14:24:43              | 14:59:37             |
| 07:57:32              | 09:46:21             |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

The task remains the same - to get the time difference but in hours, corresponding to the Stop Time of the first row and Start Time of the last row 
for each Key.

Based on the answer, I was trying something like this:

```
df['Time']=df.groupby(['Location','Event']).Date.\
           transform(lambda x : (x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0]))[~df.duplicated(['Location','Event'],keep='last')]

df['Time_h']=df.groupby(['Location','Event'])['Start Time (hh:mm:ss)','Stop Time (hh:mm:ss)'].\
            transform(lambda x,y : (x.iloc[-1]-y.iloc[0]))[~df.duplicated(['Location','Event'],keep='last')]    # This gives an error on transform
```

to get the difference in days and hours separately and then combine. Is there a better way?

Comment: What is Key?  There is no Key in your sample data listed above.

Comment: @ScottBoston: Please see the linked SO post.

Comment: So, is this one dataframe or two?

Comment: @ScottBoston: It's one dataframe.

Comment: `StartTime`/`StopTime` has 10 rows while the 'Date` dataframe has 12 rows. Does it mean some `Date` has no `StartTime`/`StopTime`? Furthermore, It looks like `StartTime`/`StopTime` doesn't in increasing order per 'Date'?

Comment: @AndyL. Please see edit. It was just a placeholder, not meant to confuse. Same no. of rows.